# Why do exclamation ! shell commands in GVIM show error: "syntax error near unexpected token (" for "ls() ("?

Tags: external-command, bash

E.g., it I do:

```
!echo a
```

or any other `!`, it first prints:

```
syntax error near unexpected token (
  ls() ( /* my alias */ )
```

and then the actual command.

The problem only happens in GVIM, not in Vim.

Ubuntu 16.10, vim 7.4.1829.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of adding `-i` to `shellcmdflags` and reading your entire `.bashrc` just for loading aliases, keep your aliases in a separate file, like `~/.bash_aliases` for Ubuntu, and add to your vimrc:

```
let $BASH_ENV = "~/.bash_aliases"
```

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Invoked-non_002dinteractively),

> #### Invoked non-interactively
>
> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for
>   example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment,
>   expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
>   the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the
>   following command were executed:
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the `PATH` variable is not used to search for the
>   filename.

Since Vim still invokes bash non-interactively, bash doesn't enable aliases. You can do so by [adding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1498/70524) to the file:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

This is harmless in an interactive shell, so adding it won't cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

The default bashrc for Ubuntu, contains the following lines at the beginning:

```
if $TERM_IS_COLOR ...
  ... 
else
  alias ls="ls -F"
  alias ll="ls -lF"
fi
```

which I had kept.

Then at some point I added:

```
shellcmdflag=-ic
```

with `i` to have access to my aliases from vim commands.

But the GVIM shell cannot show colors, and only in that case the default `alias` comes before my command, and messes things up.

For now, I will just remove the lines:

```
alias ls="ls -F"
alias ll="ls -lF"
```

and see some raw shell color commands from time to time on GVIM.