# How does Vim sets 'shell'?

Tags: variables

I have an [issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2034) with Vim in NixOS.

The problem is that Vim sets to  `shell` the path to not desired bash (non-interactive bash).

So I want to know how Vim finds a shell and sets its path to `shell` to fix the issue.

Comment: "non-interactive" bash? Do you want to add the `-i` option to bash? If so, I'd suggest https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11173/205 instead. See [`:h 'shell'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shell%27) and [`:h 'shellcmdflag'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shellcmdflag%27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is set from environment variable $SHELL. .
For example try run vim like this:

```
% env SHELL=/bin/csh vim
```