# aliased commands don't work with the shell ex command?

Tags: shell

I have a number of aliased commands in my .bashrc and they work fine on the command line. However, if I use them in Vim, they do not work. For example:

```
:!mycommand
```

results in:

```
/binbash: mycommand: command not found
```

What is the explanation?

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do that `vim` invokes shells (e.g. requested by `!` or `system()`) as non-interactive and non-login shell, which means `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` are not read. You could try making it interactive by setting `'shellcmdflag'` to   `"-ic"`.

Comment: @Hotschke There’s a better solution here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11173/343

Comment: @Rich yes, that really is better.